# Is there an alphabetic equivalent of nl or seq?

Tags: shell, seq, nl

I have a file where I'd like to number the lines using "the alphabet" (simple ascii a, b, c, etc.) instead of numbers.  So where I could do:

```
nl somefile
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
abc somefile
```

and get output like:

```
a line 1 of file
b line 2 of file
c line 3 of file
...
```

Even an alphabetic equivalent of `seq` could help -- I could use `paste` to prefix lines.

To keep things simple, my file would have 26 or less lines (so `abc` would not need to wrap letters like ...x, y, z, aa, ab, ac... kind of thing.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `bash` using `paste`, `head`, `wc` and `printf`:

```
# generate somefile
$ printf 'line %s of file\n' {1..5} > somefile

# then paste
$ paste -d ' ' <(printf '%s\n' {a..z}) somefile
a line 1 of file
b line 2 of file
c line 3 of file
d line 4 of file
e line 5 of file
f
g
...
```

As we don't know how many characters we need to generate (`a-e` in this example), we could generate the full alphabet and only merge as much lines as `somefile` has and write it down as a function:

```
function abc() { paste -d ' ' <(printf '%s\n' {a..z} | head -n $(wc -l <"$1")) "$1"; }
```

Output:

```
$ abc somefile
a line 1 of file
b line 2 of file
c line 3 of file
d line 4 of file
e line 5 of file
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use awk:

```
awk '{printf "%c\t%s\n", NR+96, $0}'
```

(97 being the ASCII decimal value of `a`)

```
% seq 1 10 |  awk '{printf "%c\t%s\n", NR+96, $0}'   
a       1
b       2
c       3
d       4
e       5
f       6
g       7
h       8
i       9
j       10
```

Comment: What happens on line 27?

Comment: @glennjackman doesn't matter ("To keep things simple, my file would have 26 or less lines")

Answer (score 0):

In bash to print any range of characters, not just alphabetic or numeric:

```
$ printf '%b\n' "$(eval printf '\\%03o' $(printf '{%d..%d}' "'!" "'~"))"
!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl knows how to increment strings, including "z" -> "aa" etc. Try this:

```
# a bash function for "alphabetic nl"
anl() {
    perl -sne 'printf "%6s\t%s", $nl++, $_' -- -nl=a "$@"
}
```

Then you can do

```
seq 50 | anl
anl file file ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's a botch, as it only works in one direction (decrementing `aa` will not give you `z`). And its kind of a useless feature that you should take care to avoid, which may be pretty hard as perl doesn't have any kind of type safety.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. What does decrementing have to do with this question? Nothing. And, as we can see from this, it's far from useless. It's OK if you don't like perl, but don't denigrate it when it's a right tool for a job.

Comment: It has anything to do with this feature. People should be aware of its limitations. The OP had limited their problem to files with less 26 lines, so if anything, your answer is off-topic. As to me denigrating perl, you're presuming quite a lot about me.

Comment: And I'm not in the mood now to do the research for you, but I think that this feature has been on the deprecation list since quite a while, and it's **very** easy to replicate with simple use of `chr` and `use overload` (and let it work consistently).